# How can I get Eclipse PHP-IDE to collapse #regions with PHP like Visual Studio does with C#?

Tags: php, eclipse

Ever since I've seen a .NET/C# developer encapsulate code in regions and have Visual Studio collapse the code I started encapsulating my php code in regions. Not quite as much fun (or as useful) when I can't collapse regions in my IDE. Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't think it's available out of the box, maybe there's a plugin or something. But what I want to point out is that the usage of #region are called as bad smell, at least on C#. Most of the time you need to create this regions because your file has too many lines of code or classes. Is this your case? If it's, you should try to split it into abstractions using differentes files and referencing on the main file.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Guilherme. Even with 100 lines of code or less in a file it would help my ADD to collapse some regions so I can focus where I need to. I'll keep looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Some where I read about coffee-bytes, which you can use on eclipse to attain region wise code folding.